# Spring Boot - how to best declare beans from a library in an application?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

As part of an evolving platform, we have a library that handles services and repositories and is used by other applications.

In the library, I have the following classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@AutoConfiguration
@EnableRetry
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class LibraryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SpringApplication(LibraryApplication.class).run(args);
    }
}


public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {}

public interface BarRepository extends MongoRepository<Bar, String> {}

public interface FooService { // methods }

public interface BarService { // methods }

@Service
public class FooServiceImpl extends FooService {

    private final FooRepository fooRepository;

    public FooServiceImpl (FooRepository fooRepository) { this.fooRepository = fooRepository; }

    // overriden methods 
}

@Service
public class BarServiceImpl extends BarService {

    private final BarRepository barRepository;

    public BarServiceImpl (BarRepository barRepository) { this.barRepository = barRepository; }

    // overriden methods 
}
```

Currently, the applications have this library declared in the pom.xml and a configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
public ApplicationBeans {

    @Bean 
    public FooService fooService() {
        return new FooServiceImpl(fooRepository);
    }

    @Bean 
    public BarService barService() {
        return new BarServiceImpl(barRepository);
    }

    // other beans
}
```

So, I have a few questions:

1. Since the library is a Spring Boot application and is declared in the pom.xml of the applications, should the library beans not be brought in to the context of the using application?
2. If not, how to best declare the services in the application? Is there a way to declare the library services without explicit declaring the repository beans? Something like:

   ```
    @Configuration
    public ApplicationBeans {

    @Bean 
    public FooService fooService() {
        return new FooServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean 
    public BarService barService() {
        return new BarServiceImpl();
    }

    // other beans
    }
   ```